# Webform is not sending body as HTML

Tags: 8, webforms

**Within the e-mail handlers** I've selected the body as '**twig template**'.
**But no HTML is sent.**

I've activated **Swiftmailer** to send attachments ... is that the problem?

```
<p>Submitted values:</p>    
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values]', webform_submission, [], options) }}
<p> URL: {{ webform_token('[current-page:url]', webform_submission, [], options) }}</p>
<p> Page name: {{ webform_token('[current-page:title]', webform_submission, [], options) }}</p>
```

**Value in body (email):**

Submitted values: *Name* sfd dsf *E-mail* test@test.com [1] *Phone* sdfsdfsdf [2] *VAT* sdfsdfdfs *Question?* Yes *Newsletter* List1, List2, List3 *Message* sdfsdf sdf sdf s dfsdfs URL: https://test.test.com/page/title/subtitle Page name: Pagename [1] test2@test.com [2] tel:sdfsdfsdf

Comment: Yes, HTML is selected but the only available HTML formatting is 'plain text'. ==> 'The list of available formats is restricted to those that escape HTML.' If you create a new format, there is no option to select to escape HTML....

Comment: nvm, that wasn't it.

Comment: So, there is nobody that can help with this issue?

Comment: Instead, try using what I use, [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue with emails sent from webform module (Drupal 9.0.7 & webform 6.0.0-alpha20), solved using following steps.

1. Install and enable Mail mail module https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail
2. Ensure email format is "Full html" at /admin/config/system/mimemail
3. Go to /admin/config/system/mailsystem and choose "Mime Mail mailer" for
   "Formatter" and "Sender" fields under default mail settings.
4. In your webform, go to settings-> Email/handlers -> Advanced tab. Make sure "Send email as HTML" is checked.

Comment: Let me check this. Thanks.